# Merge font files

Tags: c#, fonts, merge

Okay, here is the situation, I've extracted a number of font files from pdfs. These are incomplete glyph sets and I'm fine with that. But, what I am looking for is code to take the following glyph sets

GLYPH SET A:
A B D P R
GLYPH SET B:
A B X Y Z

and turn them into one solo glyph set

GLYPH SET AB:
A B D P R X Y Z

I am simply trying to condense these sets into one (probably still incomplete) glyph set. As for legality, the company that I work for has a license to redisplay the PDF files that these fonts come from (and a contractual obligation to ddisplay them exactly as published) and thus both the right and the requirement to use the fonts I am working with.

I am looking for C# code that would iterate over glyphs and insert the missing information from one into another. Actually information on how TFF, or CFF files are encoded would be a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: For anyone lurking on this question, I am currently researching the font specifications to deliver an answer, which I'll post as soon as I have it.